# sql find and remove duplicate columns with trim

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, trim

I have a table "partner_entries" with 3 columns : `our_ref | partner_ref | partner_tag` where all thoses 3 fields form the primary key.

I have a certain amount of "duplicate" rows like this :

```
42 | abc | tag1  
42 | abc  | tag1
```

As you can see it's not really duplicate because there is a space after the same word.
I can retrieve duplicates based on our_ref and partner_tag like this :

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nb_duplicates, our_ref, partner_tag
FROM     partners_entries
GROUP BY our_ref, partner_tag
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

But it also take some rows where partner_ref is really different, i just want to select thoses where partner_ref is the same but with a space after, how can I do that ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TRIM in the select and GROUP BY clauses:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nb_duplicates, our_ref, TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM partner_ref), partner_tag
FROM     partners_entries
GROUP BY our_ref, TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM partner_ref), partner_tag
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Use an extended [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) syntax to remove the newlines and other symbols from your data

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae56/3)

Comment: *btrim* might be better suited here, since there exists dirty data and full sanitation is desired.

Comment: I had to roll back to TRIM. BTRIM is only available in Postgres. MySQL does not have it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried that already as i was expecting it to work but it doesn't select any rows :/

Comment: Nice catch.  That's my mistake — I thought the question was about  Postgres.  This is one area where MySql is better, since I think its `trim()` acts like Postgres's `btrim()`

Comment: @Pontek: SQL Fiddle proves it

Comment: Thanks, I discover that it's not only a space but also a '\n', i guess that's why it's not working, i tried with replace but without sucess, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae56/2

Comment: This answer gives the normative pattern. Note that MySQL TRIM function will remove *multiple* spaces from both the *beginning* and the *end* of a string, e.g, `SELECT TRIM('  abc  ')`  --> `'abc'`. So, this pattern will find more matches than just a single space at the end of string. If the requirement is to identify the duplicates that are due to *only* a single space at the end of one string or the other, we'd need to use slightly more involved expression, for example **`IF(foo LIKE '% ',SUBSTRING(foo,1,CHAR_LENGTH(foo)-1),foo)`**.

Comment: To remove other white space characters, such as tab, newline, carriage return from anywhere in the string **`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(foo,'\n',''),'\r','','\t','')`**

Comment: @spencer7593: REPLACE will remove the symbols from the middle of the string as well. `TRIM (BOTH '\n' FROM partner_ref)` will remove the leading and trailing symbols only

Comment: Thanks all for your help, in the end i just need to do : "DELETE FROM `partners_entries` WHERE partner_ref LIKE '%\n'"
But i still learned things with my question :) Have a good day !

Comment: @cha... exactly, which is what i meant when I i said "from **anywhere** in the string".